# Drawing isochrones on map?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am a fourth year graduation student of the Amsterdam University of Applied Sciences. I am currently working on my final thesis for which I am doing research on the Amsterdam Airport catchment area.

For a case study on this catchment area, I need to draw isochrones of 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175 and 200 kilometers from Amsterdam Schiphol Airport as a starting point of my research. These isochrone boundaries provide me with the information which population lives from a specific distance (access time) from Amsterdam Schiphol Airport and gives me the opportunity to calculate travel time by public transport to Amsterdam Schiphol Airport, but also to other airports. The aim of my study is to show the amount of airport choices for passengers within a distance of 200 KM "catchment area" of Amsterdam Schiphol Airport.

Could someone help me drawing these isochrones?

Comment: Are you aware that isochrones are lines of equal travel time? They can be at 10, 20, 30 minutes but not at 10, 25, 50 km.

Comment: Maybe then I mean I need to draw driving distance isolines instead of isochrones (I am a little bit confused by the different used terminology due to lack of knowledge within this field of study). However, I thought it should be possible to draw those lines/boundaries around a picked point based upon distance. I first thought about just drawing a concentric circle, but that does not give me exact towns/spots I want to pick in order to calculate travel time. But please, correct me if I am wrong, I am only a research student without any knowledge within this field.

Answer (score 3):

**Finnish Airports Isochrones**

using the Interpolation plugin

Site analyses can benefit greatly from using “drive-time” isochrones to define the study area. Drive time isochrones are often significantly different from simple buffer areas which disregard natural barriers such as rivers or slow roads.

[image]

http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/drive%20time%20isochrones/

Plugin
http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_interpolation.html

Answer (score -5):

Try www.iso4app.com. You can have immediately isochrones and isodistances for free. Registration requires!

Comment: Are you associated with this website?  Have you used this website?  If yes to the first question then you need to disclose that within your answer every time you use it in an answer.  If yes to the second question, then please elaborate on your experience.