# Isochrones for public transport

Tags: qgis, transportation, isochrone

Is there a way to compute isochrones for public transport while using the plug-ins available in QGIS? Or is there another way for making them?

Note: I am not a software engineer which means that some of your answers might exceed my field of study regarding programing or handling specific software.

Comment: Do you have public transport data? Or is that part of the problem? If so, then this is a big problem and will depend on where on earth you are.

Comment: No, I don't have the public transport data. That is the problem. I thought that maybe the transport information can be called directly from the software as in the case of using the OSM plug-in needed for making the isochrones for cars. I am trying to compute them for Denmark.

Comment: I suspect that OSM plugin knows the speed limits on roads and works out accordingly. I doubt it knows where buses, trams, and trains go. Public transport isochrones are also very dependent on the time of day and day of week...

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit difficult to answer your question without further details, but drawing isochrones is a relatively frequent (and complex) issue. QGIS alone (including its plugins) does not provide a simple way to compute isochrones. A common solution is to use a PostGIS database along with pgRouting.

You can refer to these posts in GIS SE:

- [Drawing isochrones on map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118533/drawing-isochrones-on-map)
- [How to calculate Network Service Areas in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/how-to-calculate-network-service-areas-in-qgis)
- [Is it possible to create Isochrones in QGIS GUI?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/is-it-possible-to-create-isochrones-in-qgis-gui)
- [Which tools and methods can be used to create isochrones?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/870/which-tools-and-methods-can-be-used-to-create-isochrones)

That being said, there is a QGIS plugin called [Walking time](https://sigsemgrilhetas.wordpress.com/plugins-qgis/walking-time/), which, combined with the [Interpolation plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_interpolation.html), might be of use in your case. It may be possible to tweak it to fit your needs, but I don't know if it works well.

Answer (score 1):

See Anita's demo here:

http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/07/public-transport-isochrones-with-pgrouting/

It will require pgRouting

Comment: It will also require a public transport data set, which the questioner has just told us they don't have.