# Get Isochrones for Public Transport in QGIS

Tags: qgis, transit, isochrone

I'm using QGIS and trying to get public transportation isochrones in Montreal for 20, 40, and 60 minutes.

I was able to use the ORS plugin to do the same for cars, walking and cycling in the area. I tried to use the TravelTime plugin for public transit but the results came out very inaccurate for the Montreal area (it showed a very small area accessible by public transportation within 60 minutes and I live here so I know its way off)

I put together .csv files for all of the bus and train transit lines in the area and brought them into QGIS as delimited text layers then merged them using MMQGIS plugin

Basically I have a sample size of roughly 4000 postal codes from residents in the greater Montreal area and I want to see how many of them live within 20, 40 and 60 minutes from the Concordia University campuses (which I have points for).

Comment: At first, creating Isochrones for public transportation within QGIS is not yet possible, as you need GTFS data to create them. You may find some free services or some you need API-Keys for. The only one I found at the moment is https://www.mapnificent.net/montreal/ but with no option to export the result. You may want to try pgRouting as in this duplicate suggested https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179430/isochrones-for-public-transport or give OpenTripPlanner, an open source multimodal route planning engine with analysis function, a try.

Comment: I have the GTFS data! But I have no idea how to use it.